# How do I do the make a box lab in jeroo?

Tags: java

I have to create a single method that allows your Jeroo to drop a flower and then move ten steps. Make another method that calls the drop a flower and move ten steps method. Once finished the Jeroo should make a box pattern with flowers in each corner.

Comment: Hello, will you describe what Jeroo is? And please show some of your code you tried to create,

Comment: Do you know how to do this as a sequence of commands in your `method main()`? That is, without creating other methods.